# Unable to connect to MongoDB_4.0.0 running as service

Tags: mongodb, security

I am running MongoDB_4.0.0 as service
I enabled the security using the file

```
C:\MongoDB_4.0.0\bin\mongod.cfg
```

In my J2EE application I keep getting:

```
  org.springframework.data.mongodb.CannotGetMongoDbConnectionException: 
  Failed to authenticate to database [xeroxDB], username = [xeroxUser], password = [p*******3]
```

I created the user on  xeroxDB and admin
but its not working...

This is how I created the User:

```
------- what dbs we have?
> show dbs
admin    0.000GB
config   0.000GB
local    0.000GB
xeroxDB  0.004GB

------- switch to user admin
> use admin
switched to db admin

------- create the user
db.createUser(
 {
    user: "xeroxUser",
    pwd: "pass123",
    roles: [
        {role : "readWrite",db: "xeroxDB"},
        {role : "userAdmin",db: "xeroxDB"},
        {role : "dbOwner",db : "xeroxDB"}
    ]
  }
)

------- lets see the users
> show users
{
        "_id" : "admin.xeroxUser",
        "user" : "xeroxUser",
        "db" : "admin",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "readWrite",
                        "db" : "xeroxDB"
                },
                {
                        "role" : "userAdmin",
                        "db" : "xeroxDB"
                },
                {
                        "role" : "dbOwner",
                        "db" : "xeroxDB"
                }
        ],
        "mechanisms" : [
                "SCRAM-SHA-1",
                "SCRAM-SHA-256"
        ]
}

------- enabled the security at 
C:\MongoDB_4.0.0\bin\mongod.cfg

security:
  authorization: enabled


------- trying to login

C:\MongoDB_4.0.0\bin>mongo.exe --username xeroxUser --password pass123
MongoDB shell version v4.0.0
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 4.0.0
2018-07-06T00:30:39.683+0300 E QUERY    [js] Error: Authentication failed. :
DB.prototype._authOrThrow@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1679:20
@(auth):6:1
@(auth):1:2
exception: login failed
```

**UPDATE**

When I am adding db name (xeroxDB) as part of the connection parameters
I am able to connect from the console, but not from the J2EE application

```
mongo.exe xeroxDB --u xeroxUser --p pass123
```

And relevant POM Section

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What specific version of Spring Data for MongoDB are you using?

Comment: Do you mean the spring Mongo java driver? Its 1.5

Comment: If you are definitely using [Spring Data for MongoDB 1.5](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-mongodb/1.5.0.RELEASE), this was released in 2014 and predates all current versions of MongoDB. The original MONGO-CR authentication mechanism from 2014 is no longer supported and there have been substantial server changes since then. For full MongoDB 4.0 support (including transactions) you should use [Spring Data MongoDB 2.1.0](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.1.0.M3/reference/html/#new-features.2-1-0) (which is currently pre-release).

Comment: If you don't need 4.0-specific feature support yet, I would recommend the latest released driver. If you are still having trouble connecting after updating your Spring driver, can you edit your question to include a snippet of code or configuration for how you are providing the auth credentials? Please also include the specific driver version (x.y.z) used.

Comment: Sorry i was wrong its 2.0.8.RELEASE   I will try to upgrade it.

Comment: Can you add a snippet of code to your example showing how you are trying to authenticate (with any credentials removed)? Spring Data for MongoDB 2.0.8 should be fine for connecting to MongoDB 4.0 as long as you don't need support for features introduced in 4.0.